# Exclude content source in Search Result in SharePoint 2013 for a specific Result Source

Tags: search-results, enterprise-search

We have SharePoint 2013 and we have 2 Result Sources both configured to use Local SharePoint Protocol.

In Search result in search center we created two tabs, for example: **MyCareer**, **MyTeam**
Also, we have two content sources one for MyCareer, which has only one url and the other for MyTeam, which has several urls.

Our Requirement:
When people click on MyCareer Tab they would get the results from only MyCareer Content Source and when they click MyTeam they should only get results from MyTeam Content source only.

As I mentioned above we have created two results sources and want to know how to build query so it target specific content source instead of all content sources.

I hope I was clear about the requirements.

Answer (score 3):

You can add two pages and two search verticals.

The search criteria you should use is

1. Edit Content Search WebPart
2. Click Change Query
3. Select a query = "Result Source" from the drop down.

Here is a walk through http://www.sharepoint24x7.com/2014/10/01/article-customizing-sharepoint-2013-results-using-result-sources/

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

1. Went to the Result Source
2. Launched the Query Builder
3. Selected **Show All Managed Properties** and then selected **ContentSource**
4. Select **Not equals** and selected a manual value and typed in the content source that I wanted to exclude.

[image]